# Clustering for mixed data

Tags: r, clustering, survey

I would like to perform clustering with a dataset consisting of survey data including likert type vars, binary and categorical variables (eg age group, type of car, residence), that are >30 in total.
The objective is to identify groups of customers, based on their demography and preferences.

Would kmeans on PCA results make sense?
Any other approaches that could be suitable?

Comment: Questions asked here dozens of times before. Please try to search first. "Clustering mixed".